# Error al crear Service Client en Netbeans 9

Tags: java, netbeans-9

Intento en NetBeans 9

1. Especifico la URL del wsd
2. Elijo el paquete donde se almacenará

El error que me tira es este

> src-resolve.4.2: Error al resolver el componente 's:schema'. Se ha detectado que 's:schema' está en el espacio de nombres 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', pero no se puede hacer referencia a los componentes de este espacio de nombres desde el documento de esquema.

Comment: yo creo que el problema es que en esa versión en específico no estaba el soporte para web ni xml completo, así que deberías probar en alguna versión más reciente y ver si se sigue presentando